# The sum of three colinear rational points is equal to $O$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I'm working on a problem,

> Show that in an elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{Q}$ the sum of three colinear rational points of it is equal to $O$ exactly when the neutral element of the group $E(\mathbb{Q})$, $O$ is an inflection point of the curve.

I found the following in my notes.

> Let $C$ be a cubic curve that is defined over a field $k$ and let $O \in C(k)$. $O$ is an inflection point if and only if $P+Q+R=O$, where $P, Q, R$ are three intersection points of $C$ with a line.
>
> **Proof:**
> If $P, Q, R$ are three intersection points of $C$ with a line, then $R=PQ$. Now, $-R=P+Q$ if and only if $-R=(OO)R=O(PQ)=P+Q$. This holds exactly when $(OO)R=OR$ or $O=OO$, i.e. exactly when $O$ is an inflection point.

Could you explain this to me? I understand that if $P, Q, R$ are three intersection points of $C$ with a line, then $R=PQ$, but I am facing difficulties with the remaining.

---

**EDIT**:

Could we say it as follows?

> Let $R$ be a point of the curve.
>
> We have that $R+(-R)=O$. To add the points $R,-R$ we find the third intersection point of the line $(R,-R)$ and the curve, which is $R(-R)$.
>
> Then we take the line $(R(-R),O)$. The third intersection point is $R+(-R)=O$.
>
> That means that the line $(R(-R),O)$ is the tangent at $O$. Since $R(-R)$ is the third intersection point of the tangent at $O$, it should be $R(-R)=OO$.
>
> If we take the line $(OO,R)$ the third intersection point is $(OO)R$. So $(OO)R=-R$.
>
> So we have that the following relation holds: $P+Q=(PQ)O$, where $P,Q$ are points of the elliptic curve and $-R=(OO)R$.
>
> $P,Q,R$ are collinear, so let $R=PQ$. Then \begin{align}P+Q+R=O \iff &P+Q=-R \\ \iff &(PQ)O=(OO)R \\ \implies &RO=(OO)R\end{align}
> so $(OO,R)=(R,O),$
>
> Since the lines are the same it has to hold $OO=O$. Does this mean that $O$ is an inflection point?

Have we shown in this way both directions?

Comment: $P+Q$ according to the addition law in the elliptic C,  is the symmetrical (with respect to Ox-axes) of $R$, say $R'.$ Thus $R+R'=O$

Comment: @111 What does this mean:

(OO)R=O(PQ) ?

Comment: I think the symbol AB means the (third) point in the intersection of the cubic C and the line defined by the points A,B. Probable OO is the tangent line at O....

Comment: So $O$ is the tangent line at $O$. But what is $(OO)R$? Is it the third intersection point of the cubic $C$ and the line that is defined by the points $OO$, $R$? 
$$$$
And at $O(PQ)$, is $PQ$ the third intersection point of the cubic $C$ and the line that is defined by the points $P$, $Q$? And is $O(PQ)$ the third intersection point of the cubic $C$ and the line that is defined by the points $O$ and $PQ$ ? 
$$$$ 
Why does the equality $(OO)R=O(PQ)$ hold?

Comment: @111 I edited my post. Could you take a look at it?

Answer (score 2):

Let us write $A*B$ for the third point in the intersection of the cubic with the line through $A$ and $B$. If we fix a point $O$ on the cubic we define $A+B=O*(P*Q)$.

**Remark**

For each point $P$ of $C$, $-P=(O*O)*P$.

Infact $P+X=O$ is equivalent to $O*(P*X)=O$, implying that $O*O=P*X$, that gives (applying $*P$ to both sides) $(O*O)*P=(P*X)*P$. And the righthandside has to give $X$.

i) Assume $P,Q,R$ collinear points of $C$ such that $P+Q+R=O$. This equations leads to $P+Q=-R=(O*O)*R$.

Now $P+Q=O*(P*Q)$ and collinearity tells us that $P*Q=R$, so
$$O*R=(O*O)*R.$$ 
This can be seen as
$$R*(O*R)=O*O.$$
Now observe that $(R*(O*R))=O$ and that then $O*O=O$, that is exactly saying that $O$ is an inflection point.

ii) Assume that $O$ is an inflection point, i.e. $O*O=O$ and let us take three collinear point $P,Q,R$, i.e. $P*Q=R$.

Then $P+Q=O*(P*Q)=O*R=(O*O)*R=-R$.

Comment: I edited my post.. Could you take a look at it?