# A theorem for cubic-A generalization of Carnot theorem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I found a theorem for cubic, the theorem is a generalization of [the Carnot theorem for conic](http://www.math.uoc.gr/~pamfilos/eGallery/problems/CarnotConics.html). I'm an electrical engineer, not a mathematician. I don't know how to prove this result.

Let ABC be a triangle, Let three points $A_1, A_2, A_3$ lie on $BC$, three points $B_1, B_2, B_3$ lie on $CA$, let three points $C_1, C_2, C_3$ lie on $AB$. There is a cubic passing through the nine points $A_1, A_2, A_3, B_1, B_2, B_3, C_1, C_2, C_3$ if only if:

$$\frac{\overline{A_1B}}{\overline{A_1C}}.\frac{\overline{A_2B}}{\overline{A_2C}}.\frac{\overline{A_3B}}{\overline{A_3C}}.
\frac{\overline{B_1C}}{\overline{B_1A}}.\frac{\overline{B_2C}}{\overline{B_2A}}.\frac{\overline{B_3C}}{\overline{B_3A}}.
\frac{\overline{C_1A}}{\overline{C_1B}}.\frac{\overline{C_2A}}{\overline{C_2B}}.\frac{\overline{C_3A}}{\overline{C_3B}}=1$$

[image]

Comment: By "lying on a cubic" do you mean that there is a polynomial p in two variables,with deg(p) less or equal 3,such that p=0 at each of the 9 points?

Comment: I mean: There is a cubic passing through the nine points .....I edited

Comment: I believe @OaiThanhĐào knows this, but for the benefit of others ... "Carnot's Theorem for a Conic" is [the result I proved for an earlier answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1429054/409); it's nice to know that it has a name. I'll note that another "Carnot's Theorem" involves [concurrent perpendiculars to the sides of a triangle](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/Carnot.shtml), while *yet another* "Carnot's Theorem" relates [the sum of signed distances from a point to the sides of a triangle to the circumradius and inradius](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/carnot.shtml).

Comment: Dear Mister @Blue, there are [four theorems name after Carnot](https://vi.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Định_lý_Carnot_(hình_học))

Comment: @OaiThanhĐào: Interesting!

Comment: Dear Mister @Blue, [Cayley–Bacharach theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley–Bacharach_theorem) is a generalization of the Pascal theorem and the Pappus theorem. The problem is a generalization of the [Carnot theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/CarnotForConics.shtml) and the Menelaus theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any nine points lie on a cubic; the nine points in the question already lie on a cubic: namely, the degenerate cubic consisting of the union of the triangle's edge-lines. What the question *intends* is that the nine points, under the stated condition, lie on a *second* cubic (and therefore, determine an *pencil* of cubics). That is, whereas we expect nine points in "general position" to determine a *unique* cubic, the condition indicates that these particular nine points are in "*not-quite-general* position".

---

This can be proven with the approach I used in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1429054/409) to prove [Carnot's Theorem for Conics](http://www.math.uoc.gr/~pamfilos/eGallery/problems/CarnotConics.html). Namely, we assign coordinates
$$A := (x_A, y_A) \quad\quad B = (x_B, y_B) \quad\quad C := ( x_C, y_C )$$ and define
$$
A^{(i)} = \frac{B + a_i C}{1 + a_i} \qquad
B^{(i)} = \frac{C + b_i A}{1 + b_i} \qquad
C^{(i)} = \frac{A + c_i B}{1 + c_i} \qquad
$$
then, writing $P_x$ and $P_y$ for the coordinates of $P$, we use a determinant to express the equation of "the" cubic through our nine points:

$$\left|\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
x^3 & x^2 y & x y^2 & y^3 & x^2 & x y & y^2 & x & y & 1 \\
(A^{\prime}_x)^3 & 
(A^{\prime}_x)^2 A^{\prime}_y &
A^{\prime}_x (A^{\prime}_y)^2 & 
(A^{\prime}_y)^3 &
(A^{\prime}_x)^2 &
A^{\prime}_x A^{\prime}_y & 
(A^{\prime}_y)^2 &
A^{\prime}_x &
A^{\prime}_y & 1
\\
(A^{\prime\prime}_x)^3 & 
(A^{\prime\prime}_x)^2 A^{\prime\prime}_y &
A^{\prime\prime}_x (A^{\prime\prime}_y)^2 & 
(A^{\prime\prime}_y)^3 &
(A^{\prime\prime}_x)^2 &
A^{\prime\prime}_x A^{\prime\prime}_y & 
(A^{\prime\prime}_y)^2 &
A^{\prime\prime}_x &
A^{\prime\prime}_y & 1
\\
(A^{\prime\prime\prime}_x)^3 & 
(A^{\prime\prime\prime}_x)^2 A^{\prime\prime\prime}_y &
A^{\prime\prime\prime}_x (A^{\prime\prime\prime}_y)^2 & 
(A^{\prime\prime\prime}_y)^3 &
(A^{\prime\prime\prime}_x)^2 &
A^{\prime\prime\prime}_x A^{\prime\prime\prime}_y & 
(A^{\prime\prime\prime}_y)^2 &
A^{\prime\prime\prime}_x &
A^{\prime\prime\prime}_y & 1
\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\\
(C^{\prime\prime\prime}_x)^3 & 
(C^{\prime\prime\prime}_x)^2 A^{\prime\prime\prime}_y &
C^{\prime\prime\prime}_x (C^{\prime\prime\prime}_y)^2 & 
(C^{\prime\prime\prime}_y)^3 &
(C^{\prime\prime\prime}_x)^2 &
C^{\prime\prime\prime}_x C^{\prime\prime\prime}_y & 
(C^{\prime\prime\prime}_y)^2 &
C^{\prime\prime\prime}_x &
C^{\prime\prime\prime}_y & 1
\end{array}\right| = 0$$

A computer algebra system like *Mathematica* really helps to crunch the symbols, returning this:

$$\begin{align}
0 = 
&\phantom{\cdot}\;\left( x ( y_A - y_B ) - y ( x_A - x_B ) + x_A y_B - y_A x_B \right) \\
&\cdot\left( x ( y_B - y_C ) - y ( x_B - x_C ) + x_B y_C - y_B x_C \right) \\
&\cdot\left( x ( y_C - y_A ) - y ( x_C - x_A ) + x_C y_A - y_C x_A \right) \\
&\cdot|\triangle ABC|^7 \\
&\cdot(a_1 - a_2) (a_2 - a_3) (a_3 - a_1)\\
&\cdot(b_1 - b_2) (b_2 - b_3) (b_3 - b_1)\\
&\cdot(c_1 - c_2) (c_2 - c_3) (c_3 - c_1)\\
&\cdot(1 + a_1 a_2 a_3 b_1 b_2 b_3 c_1 c_2 c_3)
\end{align}$$

(There *must* be a better way to derive this than by a brute-force calculation of a $10$-by-$10$ determinant. Of course, it helps to take convenient starting coordinates like $A=(0,0)$, $B = (x_B,0)$, $C = (x_C,y_C)$.)

The first three factors describe the triangle's edge-lines; their product represents the **unique** conic through our nine points, **unless** one of the other factors vanishes.

Of course, $|\triangle ABC| \neq 0$ for a non-degenerate triangle. Taking our points to be distinct guarantees that $a_i - a_j \neq 0$, and so forth.  We may then draw the following conclusion:

> Nine distinct points $A^{(i)}$, $B^{(i)}$, $C^{(i)}$ on the edge-lines of a non-degenerate triangle determine a *pencil* of cubics if and only if
>   $$a_1 \; a_2 \; a_3 \; b_1 \; b_2 \; b_3 \; c_1 \; c_2 \; c_3 \;=\; -1 \tag{$\star$}$$
>   Equivalently, we can say that those nine points determine a *unique* cubic (the union of the triangle's edge-lines) if and only if
>   $$a_1 \; a_2 \; a_3 \; b_1 \; b_2 \; b_3 \; c_1 \; c_2 \; c_3 \;\neq\; -1$$

To convert to the formula in the question, we note that the constants represent *signed* ratios of *oriented* segment lengths (in the grand [Ceva tradition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem)); a ratio is *positive* if the segments point in the *same direction* along a line, and *negative* if the segments point in *opposite directions*. Thus,

$$a_1 = \frac{|B A^{\prime}|}{|A^{\prime} C|} = - \frac{|A^{\prime} B|}{|A^{\prime}C|}$$

and so forth. An odd number of sign changes ensures that $(\star)$ matches the formula in the question. $\square$

Comment: Holy  s********** ! And thanks to Mathematica for the brute force.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be a hypersurface of degree $d$ of equation $\phi(x) = 0$ in some $k^n$, $a$ a point not on $S$. Consider a line $a +  t v$ through $a$ that intersects $S$ in $n$ points given by the equation in $t$
$$\phi(a + t v ) = 0$$
Now expanding the LHS wr to the powers of $t$ we get
$$\phi(a) + \cdots  + \phi_d(v) t^d =0$$
(where $\phi_d$ is the $d$-homogenous part of $\phi$)). Therefore, the product of the roots of the above equation is ( by [Viete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas))
$$(-1)^d\frac{\phi(a)}{\phi_d(v)}$$

Therefore: if $a$,  are $b$ points not on $S$ and the line $ab$ intersects $S$ in $d$ points $c_1$, $\ldots$, $c_d$ then
$$\frac{ac_1 \cdot ac_2 \cdots ac_d}{b c_1\cdot bc_2 \cdots bc_d} = \frac{\phi(a)}{\phi(b)}$$

Consequence ( Carnot's theorem)

Let $a_1$, $\ldots$, $a_n$ points not on $S$. For every $i$ consider the intersection of the line $a_i$, $a_{i+1}$ with $S$ as $c_{i1}$, $\ldots$, $c_{id}$. Then we have

$$\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i c_{i1} \cdot a_i c_{i2} \cdots \cdot a_i c_{id}}{a_{i+1} c_{i1}\cdot a_{i+1} c_{i2}  \cdots \cdot a_{i+1} c_{id}}=1$$

Indeed, the product equals
$$\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{\phi(a_i)}{\phi(a_{i+1})} = 1$$

Notes: the theorem about the product of chords determined by an algebraic curve is due to Newton ( it generalizes the [power of a point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point))

The theorem of Carnot follows from the theorem of Newton, and generalizes results like [Menelaus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem).